# Why can't you pass a variable containing an array of "row objects" to the .excluding/.where.not method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rails-activerecord

I'm currently learning ActiveRecord and working through some testing drills in RSpec.
An abbreviated version of the test that is tripping me up is below.

I can make it pass by changing the `results` variable to `results = Row.where.not(id: rows_not_included)`, but **I can't understand why you can't pass the variable that holds the row objects to the `.excluding` method and get the expected results without specifically referencing a column**?
Am I thinking about "row objects" incorrectly, or is there something more that I don't understand? Why do you need to reference a specific column for this argument to be read the way it is intended? Why can Rails understand what an array of instance variables that points to rows in a table is when it is inside of an expectation, but *not* when it is passed as an argument for an ActiveRecord query?

Rails v: 5.2.4

```rb
    @row_1 = Row.create(:blah, :blah_blah)
    @row_2 = Row.create(:blah, :blah_blah)
    @row_3 = Row.create(:blah, :blah_blah)
    @row_4 = Row.create(:blah, :blah_blah)

    rows_not_included = [@row_1, @row_3]
    expected_result = [@row_2, @row_4]

    results = Row.excluding(rows_not_included)
    # ----->  Row.where.not(rows_not_included) produces the same results; see below
    expect(results).to eq(expected_result)
```

Output error for .where.not:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ActiveRecordObstacleCourseWeek2>)> Item.where.not(items_not_included)NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for #<Item:0x00007fa61caa1e90>
from /Users/brennastuart/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
```

Output error for .excluding:

```
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ActiveRecord>)> Item.excluding(items_not_included)
NoMethodError: undefined method `excluding' for #<Class:0x00007fcab2853ea8>
from /Users/brennas/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

Comment: can you share the  output error of rspec when this is fails

Comment: @MehmetAdilİstikbal edited the post to add the output error

Comment: what is your rails version?

Comment: @MehmetAdilİstikbal this is running on Rails 5.2.4, Ruby 2.7.4

Comment: i did some research and found out that `excluding` method introduced in rails 7. Here one blog post  about excluding. https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-7-adds-activerecord-relation-excluding

Comment: @MehmetAdilİstikbal i think do remember reading that, but i also had tried with `.where.not` with the same results, though:
`[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ActiveRecord>)> Item.where.not(items_not_included)NoMethodError: undefined method 'include?' for #<Item:0x00007fa61caa1e90>
from /Users/brennas/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in 'method_missing'`

Comment: probably you need to specify a criteria to match record in database, for example id, or name or something else.  without it rails can not decide how to make query to database.

Comment: @MehmetAdilİstikbal so even though those 'attributes' are saved to the `@row_#` instance variables, Rails cannot see what the value is as it relates to a row in the referenced table? Or to put it another way, a "row object" doesn't really exist as a "row object"?

Comment: Actually rails does the mapping between columns in database and attributes in model. The problem here is that rails does not now  what is your compare criteria. Do you want to compare them with their id's or with their names any other attributes.

Comment: if Rails doesn't know what the compare criteria is, how can the RSpec test ever pass as it is given the exact same criteria? is this because RSpec is running on ruby, but the query itself is in Rails? (which as you mentioned, uses a model to interact with the database via ActiveRecord, and that needs some sort of attribute to be able to know what entry it is supposed to be referencing?)

Answer (score 0):

You said test is passing when you assign results like this right?

```
results = Row.where.not(id: rows_not_included)
```

The query above will search rows that its `id` different from the ids of objects that given as parameter. If you specify a column name then rails will try to query with where condition that includes the column you specified and compare it with the id attributes of the given objects. I just tried some scenarios and found out this.

```
results = Row.where.not(name: rows_not_included)
```

The above code will compare the name column of the row records in database with ids of the rows_not_included objects.